# 3D touch change preview's frame

Tags: ios, point, preview, 3dtouch

previewController have preferredContentSize, i just want to ask if there have any code for preview's point, because my viewController's  nav bar is writer by myself, not system's nav bar, it's view, so when i peek, preview have nav bar, if i change  previewController's nav bar, when i pop it, finally viewController also change, so ,i just want ask if there have any code for preview to change preview's point, to change preview could visible frame.
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(kSCREENWIDTH, kSCREENHEIGHT - navHeight); 
the code change preview's size.

Answer (score 1):

do this in your UIControllerPreviewingDelegate:
 previewingController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake:(width,height);

Comment: Seems that only the height of the previewing VC can be set.